# How can we pass a java variable into pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I have a listener class which is implementing `ITestListener` in which am initializing few variables to get the total test results pass/failed skipped etc. as follows:

```java
int testPassed = context.getPassedTests().getAllResults().size();

int testFailed = context.getFailedTests().getAllResults().size();

int testSkipped = context.getSkippedTests().getAllResults().size();

int totalTests = testPassed + testFailed + testSkipped;
```

I want to use these variables in my `pom.xml` and then use those variables in turn to write a customized text file which we will be sending in the email body.

Is there any way out to do such thing ? Or we have to only write in a file using JAVA itself.

Answer (score 0):

See:

- [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java) and
- [Maven: The Complete Reference, 9.2.3. Environment Variable Properties](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html#resource-filtering-sect-enviroment-variable)

or:

- write your variables to a `.properties` file and
- use the [properties-maven-plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/properties-mvn/):

  > *The plugin reads property and xml files and declaring them as maven project properties*