# Setting the AWS region programmatically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I use aws-java-sdk version 1.11.104.   According to the [AWS credentials doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html) the default region is `us-east-1`, however when I don't set the region manually when I create a client, like this:

```
AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider =
    new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey));
AmazonS3 s3Client = 
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider).build();
```

I get this error:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException:
   Unable to find a region via the region provider chain.
   Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
```

1. **Why isn't the default region used?**

   I tried to add the following before my code above but it still doesn't work.

   ```
   System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.AWS_REGION_ENV_VAR, "us-east-1");
   ```
2. **How to set the AWS region programmatically?** (I would like to set it at runtime for all classes of my project).

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I know I can use `.withRegion()` on the clients' builder, but I was expecting a default region, or, the region picked from an environment variable through the default region provider chain.

Comment: 2nd question http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#withRegion-com.amazonaws.regions.Regions-

Comment: 1st question http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-region-selection.html

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#setRegion-java.lang.String-

Comment: @Lashane and @alfasin your links don't explain how to set the environment variable programmatically, and it doesn't explain either why `System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.AWS_REGION_ENV_VAR, "us-east-1");` doesn't work...

Answer (score 12):

I have a similar scenario, we are building an AWS abstraction layer so programmers don't have to touch any AWS Code. And I were also having problems with unit testing and tried to set the variable `AWS_REGION` with `System.setProperty(String, String)`.

The solution I've found is to set the property **aws.region** instead. The class [AwsSystemPropertyRegionProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/regions/AwsSystemPropertyRegionProvider.html) it is on the "region provider chain" and will get the value from this property.

I'm setting the property before my tests, in `@BeforeClass`:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("aws.region", "us-west-2");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It feels a little bit hacky

Answer (score 4):

> I was expecting a default region, or, the region picked from an environment variable through the default region provider chain.

Yeah as I read the code, it doesn't have a default region:

- `AmazonEC2ClientBuilder` extends (up a bit) `AwsClientBuilder`.
- `AwsClientBuilder` by default uses the `DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain`.
- `DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain` uses 3 mechanisms to determine the region:

  - `AwsEnvVarOverrideRegionProvider` which looks in the `AWS_REGION` environmental variable which you *can't* set at runtime.  Or shouldn't (see below).
  - `AwsProfileRegionProvider` which reads it out of you AWS profile file.
  - `InstanceMetadataRegionProvider` which tries to lookup which EC2 instance you are on and take its region.

> 1. Why isn't the default region used? (see these [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html))

I did not see in the code any reference to `us-east-1` in the source except in `AwsHostNameUtils.parseRegionName(...)`.  I'm not sure where that is used however.

> System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.AWS_REGION_ENV_VAR, "us-east-1");

Yeah the environment is not the same thing as a system property.  There are [gross hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java) that allow you to alter the environmental variables at runtime but user beware.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your AWS doc link is the same as the one I put in my question, and it says "If you don't select a region, then us-east-1 will be used by default." which then is confusing... Regarding the environment variables, it's just for testing, locally, because my other environments such as production grab the region from `AwsEnvVarOverrideRegionProvider`or `AwsProfileRegionProvider`. I don't want to use `.withRegion()` and I don't want all the developers in my team to touch their system just to test AWS clients.

Comment: If you want that @MaximeLaval then I would use a different `AwsRegionProviderChain`.  You can take the default one and then add in your own class which looks for a system property or env variable.

Comment: But then I would need to pass it to every client I create, same as using `.withRegion()`, and I don't want to modify the existing code, I want to be able to test it as is. I guess I'll use reflection to set environment variables.

Comment: Again ideally I don't want developers to have to do anything on their system (outside of the project). I want any developer to be able to test the project just after pulling it from the VC. I am ok with modifying src/test/resources config though.

Comment: @MaximeLaval : Did u find any solution for the same. I am looking for something similar where I just have to set the region for once .
-Thanks Arpan

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. And my problem is the permission to read the ~/.aws/config file. I change it to 644, which everyone can read it. Then it work. Hope this could help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).withRegion("us-east-1").build();
```

Comment: You must add a little description while answering.