# How to create/update OS level environment variable using the java programming?

Tags: java, operating-system, environment-variables

I have spent enough time on google to get the satiesfied `answer`,
but couldn't get any luck.

Finally, I decided to post a `question` over here.

Generally, using `JAVA` we are able to `read` the `OS environment` `variable` using the following code:

```
String value = System.getenv(env);
or 
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
```

Now, i am looking for `System.setenv(key, value)` kind of thing.

I am using `jdk-1.8` & currently working on the `Windows` but looking for `cross platform`.

Thank you in advance if any one can help me at this point of time.

**UPDATED :-**

> If this is duplicate then give me the answered URL of this question
>   which needs to be satisfy me.
>   I Believe, The [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java) is not correctly touch the point what i am asking.

Comment: What kind of environment variables are you hoping to set?

Comment: System.getEnv() gives a list of OS env. variable list. the same way i would like to set e.g. System.setEnv() so that other application which are been deployed under the same OS can consume those values.