# how to invoke shell command and make it affect latter command in scala?

Tags: scala, shell

I attempt to move my shell script to scala code with package of `sys.process`.
I find it can't save the shell context, that means, I can't replace `"ls ./somedir" !` with `"cd ./somedir" !`  `"ls ./" !`.
(ps: In this way, notation `!` will consume string as shell command and execute it after `import sys.process._` in scala)

How to execute shell commands and save it context just like terminal does?

also, hope it could support `ssh name@host` to open a remote session.

Thanks.

Comment: A process running in the JVM isn't supposed to be able to modify its own environment. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java), and the answers, for more on this topic.

Comment: I just find library called JSch. it support InputStream and OutputStream to deal shell command.But it need a wrapper to use happily and I'm doing this.Besides, because it based on SSH, so open a local SSH if you want invoke local shell command ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Ammonite shell](http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-Shell) purports to be the bash replacement you're looking for. It supports a notion of working directory, for example, as well as conveniences for running commands.

Comment: Hi, Could I use shell command in my program rather then in REPL.

Comment: I think it makes most sense to replace a bash script with a Scala script, but you can also embed ammonite http://ammonite.io/#Embedding or it's just a couple of libs if you want to reinvent your wheels https://github.com/lihaoyi/ammonite

Comment: Embedding seems has some bug at this point: https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/276#issuecomment-320557669

Comment: They have a gitter channel if you can access it. https://gitter.im/lihaoyi/Ammonite

Answer (score 0):

Have build a wheel at [git repo](https://github.com/LoranceChen/scall).
Basic shell command will use happily. advanced usage need improve yet.

For example:
create a ssh shell:
`val shell = new Shell(Auth("localhost", "username", 22, "password"))`

execute shell command:
`val lsRst: Either[Int, String] = shell.exc("ls")`
Besides, result `Left` means fail, `Right` means success.
You can get Right String data and mix with scala language.