# Setting Environment Variables in Unix Script from Java using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, shell, ant, aix, processbuilder

I am running a Java program on Unix (AIX to be specific) and need to call an external shell script.   Additionally, I need to set some environment variables that will be available to the shell script (technically, they need to be avaiable to an Ant program that the shell script invokes).   I know this setup sounds strange but my Java program is an installation program that wraps a pre-existing Ant script.   I want to use it to prompt for some passwords to feed into the Ant script as environment variables as encrypted values.

My problem is that the environment variables I add are not visible to the shell script and, by extension, my Ant script.   I am using the ProcessBuilder.enviroment() map to set this as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("build.sh", "install");

pb.directory("app_root/install"));

//if we have encrypted passwords, set them as environment variables on the child process
if (this.encryptedPasswords.size() > 0)
{
    for (Entry<String,String> entry : this.encryptedPasswords.entrySet())
    {
        String userName = entry.getKey();
        String encryptedPassword = entry.getValue();

        if (this.debug == true)
            System.out.println("Adding environment variable [" + userName + "] with value [" + encryptedPassword + "]");

        pb.environment().put(userName, encryptedPassword);
    }
}
```

My shell script (which I cannot easily change) basically looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

. ./build.env.sh

ant -buildfile build_impl.xml $*
```

The build.env.sh script sets and export some environment variables like WEBLOGIC_HOME, etc. that are static and also used by the Ant script.

This same concept has worked on Windows.   I am sure it is something with Unix/AIX that I am not familiar with.   For instance, do I need to be exported these new environment variables?   If so, how would that be done from ProcessBuilder in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java this might help

Comment: Thanks- I had seen that post which references some hacks to change your own process's environment variables.   However, I don't need to do that.   I simply need to pass new environment variables to a process that I am forking from Java.   It is just not working for me on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

If the process ask for password every time and used by the JVM, you can add from java using System.setProperty(..). This essentially same as providing an -D option for jvm argument.

Instead of

```
pb.environment().put(userName, encryptedPassword);
```

can write

```
    System.setProperty("userName",userName);
    System.setProperty("encryptedPassword", encryptedPassword);
```

Comment: Thanks.   Unfortunately, I am not calling a JVM (or even Ant) directly and have to go through this shell script, which I cannot easily change.   Therefore, my plan was to use environment variables an have them propagate down to the child processes.

Comment: Are you adding the host machine environment variable?

Comment: Not sure exactly what this means but if you mean do the new environment variable names conflict with existing environment variables, the answer is no.

Comment: You can do something like     -    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("build.sh", "-c", "echo $username"); Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
        env.put("username", value);