# how to use environment variables in tomcat without restarting Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a tomcat server with several applications. Then, I gonna deploy spring boot application on tomcat. But before deploy I set an environment variable in my server. Because of This application should use the environment variable. So I wish not to restart my tomcat after set new environment variable in my server.

Have you any solution? Help me, please?

Comment: Environment variables normally cannot be changed for a running process. You should consider to use another mechanism like a properties file or a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) from Java without resorting to [dirty tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201825/276232).

You can, however, change the values of *system properties*. Consider using system properties instead of environment variables to adjust the behavior of your application.

Better yet, don't use globally-visible/mutatable configuration and instead configure components individually through some other mechanism, such as a configuration file.