# How do I set an environment variable from within Kotlin code?

Tags: java, kotlin

While writing tests, some of the target code behaves differently depending on the value of a certain environment variable. In order to test its functionality, I need to change the variable and execute the code being tested. Unfortunately, there seems to be no sensible way to do it from within our Spek tests. The map that `System.getenv()` gives me is read-only.

Comment: See answer beginning ["*For use in scenarios where you need to set specific environment values for unit tests*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201825/1898563)

Comment: Not sure how this solves the issue, @Michael. It's a) a horrid hack and, b) not written in Kotlin.

Comment: Java methods are interoperable with kotlin

Comment: Also, using `org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.EnvironmentVariables` it's possible to sidestep the issue (without the hack), but Spek doesn't currently pick it (or at least my corporate endorsed release doesn't).