# Jenkins throw java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, reflection, environment-variables

I am trying to set environment variable through a unit test, when I am running my code on the local machine it is working fine.

But when I deploying it on Jenkins pipeline it starts throwing an exception.

Exception :-

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment

Code snippet :-

```java
Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
Field theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
Map<String, String> env = (Map<String, String>) theEnvironmentField.get(null);
env.clear();
env.putAll(newenv);
Field theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
Map<String, String> cienv = (Map<String, String>) theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null);
cienv.clear();
cienv.putAll(newenv);
```

Comment: did you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201825/8035260

Answer (score 2):

You're fixing the wrong problem. Your business code should never directly depend on environment variable, there should be an isolation layer in between. Decouple your input from your service code, and you will no longer need to mock environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

That field probably doesn't exist on your `java.lang.ProcessEnvironment` class.

A quick check should show you all the actual fields you have access to:

```
Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
for (Field field : processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    System.out.print(field.getName() + "\n");
}
```

In my case, I ran into the same error, and quickly discovered the only fields my `ProcessEnvironment` has are the following:

```
theEnvironment
theUnmodifiableEnvironment
MIN_NAME_LENGTH
```

My best understanding is that `theEnvironment` has replaced `theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment`, and what you actually want to also replace is `theUnmodifiableEnvironment`, so that your code reads like so:

```
Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
Field theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
Map<String, String> env = (Map<String, String>) theEnvironmentField.get(null);
env.clear();
env.putAll(newenv);
Field theUnmodifiableEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theUnmodifiableEnvironment");
theUnmodifiableEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
Map<String, String> umenv = (Map<String, String>) theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null);
umenv.clear();
umenv.putAll(newenv);
```

I'm assuming you're following something like https://sites.google.com/site/androcoding/classroom-news/howtosetenvironmentparametersusingjava from 2012, and our `ProcessEnvironment` class is just different in the version of Java we're using now in what fields it has.

Comment: umenv putAll will throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

it's a UnmodifiableMap not support update
public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }