# How to pass environment variables to Asciidoctor-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, asciidoctor, plantuml

I'm using asciidoctor-maven-plugin and asciidoctor-diagram to generate PlantUML diagrams (more specifically [C4-PlantUML](https://github.com/plantuml-stdlib/C4-PlantUML) diagrams). When generating those diagrams, output is polluted by these kind of messages

```
[Log] "dynamic undefined legend colors" requires PlantUML version >= 1.2021.6, therefore only static assigned colors are used
```

I tracked them down to asciidoctor-diagram embedding - in its source, lo less, a reasonably old version of PlantUML ([see their Github source](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-diagram/tree/v2.1.2/lib/asciidoctor-diagram/plantuml)).
Fortunatly, there is in asciidoctor-diagram plantuml [converter.rb](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-diagram/blob/v2.1.2/lib/asciidoctor-diagram/plantuml/converter.rb) class some code to use PlantUML provided externally through an environment variable named `DIAGRAM_PLANTUML_CLASSPATH`.

But as I use asciidoctor-diagram through asciidoctor-maven-plugin, how can I set that environment variable from my Maven POM **without** setting it in the maven launch ? Indeed, I want to use a dependency from my pom and [maven-dependency-plugin properties](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/properties-mojo.html) goal to have it correct on any machine without configuration.

I've already tried using asciidoctor-maven-plugin configuration `attributes`, but it didn't seem to work.

Is there any other way to inject environment variables into asciidoctor-maven-plugin ?

**EDIT 1** I've also tried using the properties-maven-plugin to add the environment variable to my maven build this way

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Set DIAGRAM_PLANTUML_CLASSPATH from PlantUML maven dependency PATH</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>DIAGRAM_PLANTUML_CLASSPATH</name>
                                    <value>${net.sourceforge.plantuml:plantuml:jar}</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But it changed nothing

**EDIT 2**

So, after some reflection, I had to resolve to use the age-long solution : debugging the culprit code (in this case, asciidoctor-maven-plugin).
In `AsciidoctorMojo#execute()`, in a long chain of calls, we initialize a JRuby interpreter (in `JRubyAsciidoctor#createRubyRuntime`).
When creating this interpreter, we pass the system environment. This system environment **DO NOT** include my `DIAGRAM_PLANTUML_CLASSPATH` variable, so I guess the properties-maven-plugin does not really set it as environment variable for the whole maven build - or there has been some changes in recent maven versions.

However, this `JRubyAsciidoctor#createRubyRuntime` method accepts as input a map of environment variables. Can we manipulate it ? **Absolutely not** as it is a private method.

And guess what ? `DIAGRAM_PLANTUML_CLASSPATH` doesn't appear in the list because it's not an environment variable, but a system property, which is quite different.

So the question is more "how can I create an environment variable ? Or inject an environment variable in my ruby env prior to running my build ?"

Comment: in my case i was able to pass environment variable as configuration attribute like `<username>${ES_CONFLUENCE_USER}</username>`. So, i used the same semantic, as you mentioned in your snippet. Maybe try to pass environment variable in uppercase

Answer (score 1):

So, I've established in the question that what was not working was the injection of the environment variable into JRuby : As default, Java doesn't allow setting environment variable, and on the other hand asciidoctor only allow injection through environment variable. So I **had** to create that environment variable.
Hopefully, Stackoverflow already answers that question : [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/318239/15619).
My only point was doing that in a maven build. Enter [GMaven Plus](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus). Using this plugin the following way

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Put PlantUML path in that damn DIAGRAM_PLANTUML_CLASSPATH environment variable</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scripts>
                                <script>${project.basedir}/src/build/groovyScripts/set_PlantUML_path_in_system_environment.groovy</script>
                            </scripts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Notice the preliminary call to dependency-maven-plugin to obtain all dependencies paths as properties.

THen I created a very small Groovy script

```
log.debug "PlantUML dependency path is ${project.properties['net.sourceforge.plantuml:plantuml:jar']}"

setEnvironmentVars(['DIAGRAM_PLANTUML_CLASSPATH':project.properties['net.sourceforge.plantuml:plantuml:jar']])
```

And it was enough to have asciidoctor-maven-plugin working.

**CAVEAT**: I'm quite sure this won't work with recent Java releases like Java 14 and Java 17. Anyway, in Java 11, it works!