# Java Playwright + Browserless ignore browser download

Tags: java, headless, playwright

I am developing a simple prototype with Java + Playwright + Browserless. I was wondering if it's possible to avoid downloading the browsers in AWS.

```
Playwright build of chromium v956323 downloaded to /home/ec2-user/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-956323
Playwright build of ffmpeg v1007 downloaded to /home/ec2-user/.cache/ms-playwright/ffmpeg-1007
Playwright build of firefox v1313 downloaded to /home/ec2-user/.cache/ms-playwright/firefox-1313
Playwright build of webkit v1596 downloaded to /home/ec2-user/.cache/ms-playwright/webkit-1596
```

Sometimes it will run in browserless and I think if so I won't need the browser but I don't really know is this possible. Or even running in browserless would I need the browsers?

If so, how can I do that in Java?

I want to do it programmatically because depending of the parameters sometime I need them, sometimes I don't; is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "browserless"?
In case you mean "headless": Yes, you also need to download the browsers when running in headless mode.

Comment: Delegating the call to a external provider Browserless is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the browser download by setting an environment variable `PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1`

See the docs here: https://playwright.dev/java/docs/browsers#skip-browser-downloads

Comment: But i want to do it programmatically i mean depending of the configuration sometimes it will run in the browsers in the same machine and sometimes in different providers.

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit. How to set an env var programmatically in Java depends on your OS, lots of possibilities covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String,String> env = new HashMap<>();
env.put("PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD","1");
try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create(new Playwright.CreateOptions().setEnv(env))) {
        BrowserType chromium = playwright.chromium();
        Browser browser = chromium.launch();
        Page page = browser.newPage();
        page.onRequest(request -> System.out.println(">> " + request.method() + " " + request.url()));
        page.onResponse(response -> System.out.println("<<" + response.status() + " " + response.url()));
        page.navigate("https://example.com");
        browser.close();
    }
}
```