# Exporting environmental variables in Clojure / Babashka

Tags: clojure, scripting, environment-variables, babashka

I am trying to write an install script in `babaska` for my other `babaska` script (for some fun homogeneity).

Export doesn't seem to work using:

```
(shell "export NAME=" value)
```

Is there a canonical way to set environmental variables in Clojure / Babashka?

Answer (score 1):

`export` is shell built-in; you can not call it outside a shell.  So
what you want to do instead is run your command with another
environment.  This can be done in [`sh` with the `:env`
option](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.shell/sh).  E.g.

```clj
(-> (shell/sh "sh" "-c" "echo $X" :env {"X" "Hello"}) :out)
```

#### edit: global state for environment

At least on the JVM, [there is no easy way to change the
environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java).
So you are better off, writing your own function to do the calls and
merge with your own global environment.

This example uses an atom to keep the environment around:

```clj
(def sh-env (atom {}))

(defn export!
  [m]
  (swap! sh-env merge m))

(defn sh
  ([cmd]
   (sh cmd {}))
  ([cmd env]
   (apply shell/sh (concat cmd [:env (merge @sh-env env)]))))

;;;

(def echo ["sh" "-c" "echo $X"])

(prn (sh echo))

(export! {"X" "Hello"})

(prn (sh echo))

(prn (sh echo {"X" "Goodbye"}))

(export! {"X" "Goodbye"})

(prn (sh echo))

; {:exit 0, :out "\n", :err ""}
; {:exit 0, :out "Hello\n", :err ""}
; {:exit 0, :out "Goodbye\n", :err ""}
; {:exit 0, :out "Goodbye\n", :err ""}
```

Comment: I need to set the env variable permanently in the install. Is there a way to do this using your answer?

Comment: Not on the JVM (yeah, there are ways, but they are hacky). You are better off writing your own function doing the calls. Then have some global state like an atom or a dynamic binding, if that fits your usecase better, around, where you keep those env vars and pass them down or merge them with per function-call arguments.

Answer (score 1):

They way to set environment variables with `shell` is like this:

```clj
(shell {:extra-env {"NAME" "FOOBAR"}} command)
```

See docs [here](https://github.com/babashka/process/blob/master/API.md#babashka.process/shell).

Comment: Anyway you could implement this in an install script? Save the variable names somewhere that can reused or something?
I'd LOVE to stay babashka only for a project but if not I'll write a shell script to incorporate what's needed.

Comment: You could of course define the option to shell in a variable :)